# Error usando vectores en Java

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente linea de código `calificacion [0] = 3.5,4.2,4.6,5.0,4.5,4.0;` 
me gustaría saber por que me da error a la hora de ejecutarlo, se que es por la forma en que separe los números que puse en el vector y están en `double` . No se cual es la forma correcta de separar los números en `double` . Espero me puedan ayudar gracias.
estoy trabajando en Java con `vectores`.

Answer (score 2):

No se si entiendo demasiado tu pregunta,

Pero la declaración de arrays del tipo double en Java es algo así:

```
double calificacion [] = {3.5,4.2,4.6,5.0,4.5,4.0};
```

Comment: `calificacion [0] ={3.5,4.2,4.6,5.0,4.5,4.0};
        calificacion [1] = 2.5+3.2+2.6+3.0+4.+3.0;
        calificacion [2] = 4.5+2.2+4.6+3.0+5.3+4.0;
        calificacion [3] = 1.5+4.2+2.6+4.0+2.3+3.0;
        calificacion [4] = 2.5+3.2+3.6+3.0+3.2+2.0; `

No se como hacer para que en vez de sumarlo sea solamente con una lista.. es decir que se muestren todos... a la hora de imprimirlo
@Federico

Comment: Justamente, no lo declares como 

calificacion[0] = algo

sino como 

calificacion [] = algo

Comment: Si lo que estas intentando hacer es poner varios double dentro del indice (calificacion[0]), entonces necesitas un array doble, en ese caso tu declaración sería:

int cantidadDeRegistros= 4;
double [][] calificacion  = new double[cantidadDeRegistros][];

calificacion[0] = {3.5,4.2,4.6,5.0,4.5,4.0};

Comment: @NahumDeavila por lo visto tu problema parece ser más sobre Java elemental. Te recomiendo que tomes unas clases donde te enseñen desde los primeros pasos.

Answer (score 0):

para llenar un vector de tipo double en java puede ser así:

```
double calificacion[] = {3.5,4.2,4.6,5.0,4.5,4.0};
```

también puedes usar un bucle for para ingresar las calificaciones:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Arreglo {

public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    double calificacion[] = new double[6];

    //rutina de ingreso
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        System.out.print("Ingrese numero: ");
        calificacion[i] = sc.nextDouble();
    }//fin for

    //rutina de impresion
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        System.out.println(calificacion[i]);
    }//fin for
   }//fin main           
  }//fin clase
```